# Python add to empty records

Tags: python, arrays, record

Using records from numpy in python I want to start with an empty record `aa` and I have array `bb` and array `cc`. Such as:

```
#aa = empty record (that take float)
bb = np.array([1,2,3])
cc = np.array([9,9,9])
```

Now I want to add to `aa` the two arrays, such that array `bb` has attribute name `bb` and array `cc` has attribute name `cc`

```
aa = numpy.lib.recfunctions.append_fields(aa,'bb',bb,dtypes=float,usemask=False,asrecarray=True)
aa = numpy.lib.recfunctions.append_fields(aa,'cc',cc,dtypes=float,usemask=False,asrecarray=True)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Retreiving variables names is not something you want to do in Python. If you want to add (list, name) tuples to a numpy array, simply use `append`:

```
bb=np.array([1,2,3])
cc=np.array([9,9,9])
myArray=numpy.array([(bb,"bb"),(cc,"cc")],dtype=object)
```

And if you want to add one more array:

```
myArray=numpy.append(myArray,[(dd,"dd")],axis=0)
```

Comment: What do you mean "Retrieving variables names is not something you want to do in Python"? I want to use records because i can do myArray.bb and get the array of bb easily. Thank you for replying, but the solution doesn't give record

Comment: Have you looked into dictionnaries ? If you want to achieve easy access: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries